# Rails + MongoID - Querying by attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I have a model like this:

```
class Lesson
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :title, :type => String
  field :category, :type => String
  field :price, :type => Float
  field :description, :type => String
  field :user_id, :type => String


  validates_presence_of :title
  validates_presence_of :category
  validates_presence_of :price
  validates_presence_of :user_id

  attr_accessible :title, :category, :description, :price

end
```

And I am trying to query like this:

```
@lessons_by_user = Lesson.find_by_user_id current_user.id
```

And I am getting:

> undefined method `find_by_user_id' for Lesson:Class

How can I query by a specific attribute in MongoID?

I know how to do it like this:

```
@lessons = Lesson.all(:conditions=>{:user_id=>current_user.id.to_s})
```

but I am wondering if there is a shortcut...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Mongoid doesn't have the ActiveRecord style auto-created finder methods, it only supports a limited set of [predefined finder methods](http://two.mongoid.org/docs/querying/finders.html):

- `Model.all`
- `Model.count`
- `Model.exists?`
- `Model.find`
- `Model.find_or_create_by`
- `Model.find_or_initialize_by`
- `Model.first`
- `Model.last`

However, it does have a general purpose [`where` method](http://two.mongoid.org/docs/querying/criteria.html#where) so you say this:

```
@lessons = Lesson.where(:user_id => current_user.id)
```

`where` is chainable as well (just like `where` in newer versions of ActiveRecord) so you can add more conditions or specify the ordering by chaining more criteria calls.

Answer (score 3):

Since the version 3.0.0 of Mongoid, you can also do:

```rb
@lessons = Lesson.find_by(user_id: current_user.id)
```

Contrary to `where`, it will raise a `Mongoid::Errors::DocumentNotFound` exception if the request returns no result. It's the default behavior, but if you set the `raise_not_found_error` configuration option to `false`, it will just return `nil` in this case.

Source: http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/querying.html

Comment: Thanks for the "2 vs 3" doc fixes above. Even AR is moving towards `find_by` instead of all that nasty `find_by_user_id` stuff in `method_missing`.